# Find pages that link to another URL?

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, backlinks

IIRC, Google used to let you do a search for all pages that link to a URL, but I can't find that method any more. Also, I don't see it in Webmaster Tools either.

I am probably overlooking something, but how can I find out who links to a specific URL on my website?

Comment: There used to be "link:" operator for this but it is no longer supported.

Comment: https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-recommends-no-longer-using-link-operator/183532/

Comment: Quote: "Not only has John Mueller recommended no longer using the command, but it appears to no longer be working at all the way it used to." The article doesn't go on to say how it is working differently today compared to before.

Comment: Never mind. It doesn't work *at all* today. Duh.

Comment: I believe it used to be `linkto:` but I'm also now looking for a way to do this. I could never remember whether there was a space after the colon or not to make the search work but Google used to let you do this and I'm just realizing they stopped letting us "spy" on links like this. Too bad, because it was good for prospecting clients. :)

Answer (score 8):

Webmaster Tools has a feature that allows you to see which sites link to your site.

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/external-links

It should be a comprehensive list of all links that Google has discovered. You can also download the latest links it has found as well as other data.

I don't believe that Google provides a way to sort the inbound links for specific URLs, but you can download the csv files that Google provides and play around with it.

Comment: `comprehensive list of all links` <-- this part is not true. Google only provides a 'sample' of links and often only recent ones. Google Search Console has never publicly published a comprehensive list of backlinks... If you want a more comprehensive list then you need to use Majestic SEO or Ahrefs.

Comment: This functionality has moved to "Links" bottom of left nav in Google Search Console https://search.google.com/u/2/search-console/links